# Single citation not found, IEEE Template, Overleaf

Tags: bibtex, citing, ieeetran, overleaf, ieeeconf

I am using IEEE double column template in Overleaf:
https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/preparation-of-papers-for-ieee-sponsored-conferences-and-symposia/zfnqfzzzxghk

I am including citations as:

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranN}
\bibliography{references}
```

*All of me citations work perfectly, except the following one:*

```
My text \cite{BORGES2018112}. More text.
```

And in the bib file:

```
@article{BORGES2018112,
title = {What's in a GitHub Star? Understanding Repository Starring Practices in a Social Coding Platform},
journal = {Journal of Systems and Software},
volume = {146},
pages = {112--129},
year = {2018},
issn = {0164--1212},
doi = {https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jss.2018.09.016},
url = {http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0164121218301961},
author = {Hudson Borges and Marco [Tulio Valente]}
}
```

I am not sure what is wrong. The rest of the citations work perfectly, but I keep getting a `[?]` where this one should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem were the brackets in the authors' name. I changed it to the following, and now it works:

```
@article{BORGES2018112,
title = {What's in a GitHub Star? Understanding Repository Starring Practices in a Social Coding Platform},
journal = {Journal of Systems and Software},
volume = {146},
pages = {112--129},
year = {2018},
issn = {0164--1212},
doi = {https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jss.2018.09.016},
url = {http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0164121218301961},
author = {Hudson Borges and Marco {Tulio Valente}}
}
```